# Link libraries to phonegap / cordova without eclipse on android (facebook sdk)

Tags: android, cordova, linker

i am using cordova 3.0 and i would like to use a plugin (Facebook auth plugin). My problem is that i don't know how to link the Facebook auth plugin to the facebook SDK without using Eclipse.

I don't see any file to reference external .jar ...

I must to install eclipse to do that?

Thx!

Comment: Did you found the answer ? I have same issue , your answer will help me lot.

Comment: In a brief: http://aaroncraig.com/include-facebook-sdk-your-android-app-without-eclipse